# Is notation $\sum \limits_k C(r, m+k)C(s, n-k) =C(r+s, m+n)$ for Vandermonde identity correct?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]
Source http://fmwww.bc.edu/gross/MT903/finalans.pdf

I think there should be $\sum \limits_k C(r, k)C(s, m+n-k)$ above rather than $\sum \limits_k C(r, m+k)C(s, n-k)$. Is the above notation for the Vandermonde identity correct?

That's different from what I see in my book below.

[image]

Source: A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates: Counting Strategies by Titu Andreescu,Zuming Feng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two identities are equivalent, and both go by the name *Vandermonde identity*. If we start with the sum

$$\sum_k\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n-k}\;,\tag{1}$$

for instance, we can let $\ell=m+k$, so that $k=\ell-m$, and substitute to get

$$\sum_k\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n-k}=\sum_\ell\binom{r}\ell\binom{s}{n-(\ell-m)}=\sum_\ell\binom{r}\ell\binom{s}{m+n-\ell}\;.$$

This is just your version with $r$ for your $m$, $s$ for your $n$, $m+n$ for your $k$, and the index $\ell$ for your $i$. It’s not necessary in either form to specify the bounds on the index, because the sum is simply over all non-zero terms. In your version, for instance, $\binom{m}i=0$ if $i<0$, and $\binom{n}{k-i}=0$ if $i>k$, so you could just as well write $\sum_i\binom{m}i\binom{n}{k-i}$.

Answer (score 2):

Under the convention that $\binom{n}{i}=0$ if $i\notin\{0,\dots,n\}$  the identity can be written as:$$\binom{m+n}{k}=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}$$ 
If $S_k:=\left\{ \langle i,j\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}^{2}\mid i+j=k\right\} $
then you can also write:$$\binom{m+n}{k}=\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle\in S_k}\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j}$$
Note that in the notation that you are wondering about we have: $$\langle m+k,n-k\rangle\in S_{m+n}$$